# Element hiding under others html

Tags: html, css

my div container is not showing completely. some part is hidden underneath my navbar. how can I stop that by default in my css?[image]I have provided the html and css codes. Some one should kindly read through and run it if possible then suggest possible solution. thanks.

**Html**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Headers - 4</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/reset.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/imarkett.css" />
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat|Ubuntu"/>
     <!-- Boostrap links -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Header Start -->
    <header class="site-header">
      <div class="wrapper site-header__wrapper">
        <div class="site-header__start">
          <a href="#" class="brand">iMARKETT</a>
          <div class="search">
            <button class="search__toggle" aria-label="Open search">
              Search
            </button>
            <form class="search__form" action="">
              <label class="sr-only" for="search">Search</label>
              <input
                type="search"
                name=""
                id="search"
                placeholder="search..."
              />
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="site-header__end">
          <nav class="nav">
            <button class="nav__toggle" aria-expanded="false" type="button">
              menu
            </button>
            <ul class="nav__wrapper">
              <li class="nav__item active">
                <a href="#">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    width="24px"
                    height="24px"
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                    class="nav-icon"
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M22,9.45,12.85,3.26A1.52,1.52,0,0,0,12,3a1.49,1.49,0,0,0-.84.26L2,9.45,3.06,11,4,10.37V20a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h5V16h4v5h5a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V10.37l.94.63Z"
                      class="active-item"
                      style="fill-opacity: 1"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M22,9.45L12.85,3.26a1.5,1.5,0,0,0-1.69,0L2,9.45,3.06,11,4,10.37V20a1,1,0,0,0,1,1h6V16h2v5h6a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V10.37L20.94,11ZM18,19H15V15a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H10a1,1,0,0,0-1,1v4H6V8.89l6-4,6,4V19Z"
                      class="inactive-item"
                      style="fill: currentColor"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>Home</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    width="24px"
                    height="24px"
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                    class="nav-icon"
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M16,17.85V20a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H1a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V17.85a4,4,0,0,1,2.55-3.73l2.95-1.2V11.71l-0.73-1.3A6,6,0,0,1,4,7.47V6a4,4,0,0,1,4.39-4A4.12,4.12,0,0,1,12,6.21V7.47a6,6,0,0,1-.77,2.94l-0.73,1.3v1.21l2.95,1.2A4,4,0,0,1,16,17.85Zm4.75-3.65L19,13.53v-1a6,6,0,0,0,1-3.31V9a3,3,0,0,0-6,0V9.18a6,6,0,0,0,.61,2.58A3.61,3.61,0,0,0,16,13a3.62,3.62,0,0,1,2,3.24V21h4a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V17.47A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,20.75,14.2Z"
                      class="inactive-item"
                      style="fill-opacity: 1"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M20.74,14.2L19,13.54V12.86l0.25-.41A5,5,0,0,0,20,9.82V9a3,3,0,0,0-6,0V9.82a5,5,0,0,0,.75,2.63L15,12.86v0.68l-1,.37a4,4,0,0,0-.58-0.28l-2.45-1V10.83A8,8,0,0,0,12,7V6A4,4,0,0,0,4,6V7a8,8,0,0,0,1,3.86v1.84l-2.45,1A4,4,0,0,0,0,17.35V20a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H22a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V17.47A3.5,3.5,0,0,0,20.74,14.2ZM16,8.75a1,1,0,0,1,2,0v1.44a3,3,0,0,1-.38,1.46l-0.33.6a0.25,0.25,0,0,1-.22.13H16.93a0.25,0.25,0,0,1-.22-0.13l-0.33-.6A3,3,0,0,1,16,10.19V8.75ZM6,5.85a2,2,0,0,1,4,0V7.28a6,6,0,0,1-.71,2.83L9,10.72a1,1,0,0,1-.88.53H7.92A1,1,0,0,1,7,10.72l-0.33-.61A6,6,0,0,1,6,7.28V5.85ZM14,19H2V17.25a2,2,0,0,1,1.26-1.86L7,13.92v-1a3,3,0,0,0,1,.18H8a3,3,0,0,0,1-.18v1l3.72,1.42A2,2,0,0,1,14,17.21V19Zm7,0H16V17.35a4,4,0,0,0-.55-2l1.05-.4V14.07a2,2,0,0,0,.4.05h0.2a2,2,0,0,0,.4-0.05v0.88l2.53,1a1.5,1.5,0,0,1,1,1.4V19Z"
                      class="active-item"
                      style="fill: currentColor"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>My Network</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    width="24px"
                    height="24px"
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                    class="nav-icon"
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M2,13H22v6a1,1,0,0,1-1,1H3a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V13ZM22,8v4H2V8A1,1,0,0,1,3,7H7V6a3,3,0,0,1,3-3h4a3,3,0,0,1,3,3V7h4A1,1,0,0,1,22,8ZM15,6a1,1,0,0,0-1-1H10A1,1,0,0,0,9,6V7h6V6Z"
                      class="inactive-item"
                      style="fill-opacity: 1"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M21,7H17V6a3,3,0,0,0-3-3H10A3,3,0,0,0,7,6V7H3A1,1,0,0,0,2,8V19a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H21a1,1,0,0,0,1-1V8A1,1,0,0,0,21,7ZM9,6a1,1,0,0,1,1-1h4a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V7H9V6ZM20,18H4V13H20v5Zm0-6H4V9H20v3Z"
                      class="active-item"
                      style="fill: currentColor"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>Jobs</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    width="24px"
                    height="24px"
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                    class="nav-icon"
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M21,8H8A1,1,0,0,0,7,9V19a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H18l4,3V9A1,1,0,0,0,21,8Zm-4,8H12V15h5Zm1-3H11V12h7ZM17,4V6H6A1,1,0,0,0,5,7v8H3a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V4A1,1,0,0,1,3,3H16A1,1,0,0,1,17,4Z"
                      class="inactive-item"
                      style="fill-opacity: 1"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M21,8H8A1,1,0,0,0,7,9V19a1,1,0,0,0,1,1H18l4,3V9A1,1,0,0,0,21,8ZM20,19.11L18.52,18H9V10H20v9.11ZM12,15h5v1H12V15ZM4,13H5v2H3a1,1,0,0,1-1-1V4A1,1,0,0,1,3,3H16a1,1,0,0,1,1,1V6H15V5H4v8Zm14,0H11V12h7v1Z"
                      class="active-item"
                      style="fill: currentColor"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>Messaging</span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav__item">
                <a href="#">
                  <svg
                    viewBox="0 0 24 24"
                    width="24px"
                    height="24px"
                    x="0"
                    y="0"
                    preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet"
                    class="nav-icon"
                    focusable="false"
                    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
                  >
                    <path
                      d="M18.94,14H5.06L5.79,8.44A6.26,6.26,0,0,1,12,3h0a6.26,6.26,0,0,1,6.21,5.44Zm2,5-1.71-4H4.78L3.06,19a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.06.28,0.75,0.75,0,0,0,.75.76H10a2,2,0,1,0,4,0h6.27A0.74,0.74,0,0,0,20.94,19Z"
                      class="inactive-item"
                      style="fill-opacity: 1"
                    ></path>
                    <path
                      d="M20.94,19L19,14.49s-0.41-3.06-.8-6.06A6.26,6.26,0,0,0,12,3h0A6.26,6.26,0,0,0,5.79,8.44L5,14.49,3.06,19a0.71,0.71,0,0,0-.06.28,0.75,0.75,0,0,0,.75.76H10a2,2,0,1,0,4,0h6.27A0.74,0.74,0,0,0,20.94,19ZM12,4.75h0a4.39,4.39,0,0,1,4.35,3.81c0.28,2.1.56,4.35,0.7,5.44H7L7.65,8.56A4.39,4.39,0,0,1,12,4.75ZM5.52,18l1.3-3H17.18l1.3,3h-13Z"
                      class="active-item"
                      style="fill: currentColor"
                    ></path>
                  </svg>
                  <span>Notifications</span>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>
    <!-- Header End -->
     <!--section categories--->
     <div class="categories">
       <table width=100% height=100%>
       <tr>
         <td st>Post ad</td>
         <td>Housing and Property</td>
         <td>Phones and Gadgets</td>
         <td>Electronics</td>
         <td>Furniture and Home appliances</td>
         <td>Other things</td>
       </tr>
     </table>
     </div>

     <div class="container-sm test">100% wide until small breakpoint</div>
   <!--  <div class="container-md test">100% wide until medium breakpoint</div>
     <div class="container-lg test">100% wide until large breakpoint</div>
     <div class="container-xl test">100% wide until extra large breakpoint</div>
     <div class="container-xxl test">100% wide until extra extra large breakpoint</div>
    --->

    

    <script src="js/header-4.js"></script>
    <!--boostrap links--->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

**css**:

```
/* 
** The Header Media Queries **
** Tweak as per your needs **
*/
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding:0px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
html{
  height: 100%;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  line-height: 1rem;
}
body{
  widows: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #222222
}

.site-header {
  position: relative;
  background-color:#87ceeb; }

.site-header__start {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; }

.site-header__end {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; }

.site-header__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem; }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .site-header__wrapper {
      padding-top: 0;
      padding-bottom: 0; } }
@media (min-width: 800px) {
  .nav__wrapper {
    display: flex; } }

@media (max-width: 799px) {
  .nav__wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(100% + 35px);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: #d9f0f7;
    visibility: hidden;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-100%);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-out, opacity 0.3s ease-out; }
    .nav__wrapper.active {
      visibility: visible;
      opacity: 1;
      transform: translateY(0); } }

.nav__item:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 0.5rem; }

.nav__item a {
  display: block;
  padding: 1rem;
  border-left: 4px solid transparent; }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .nav__item a {
      text-align: center;
      border-left: 0;
      border-bottom: 4px solid transparent; } }
.nav__item svg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 28px;
  height: 28px;
  margin-right: 1rem; }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .nav__item svg {
      display: block;
      margin: 0 auto 0.5rem; } }
.nav__item.active a {
  border-left-color: #222; }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .nav__item.active a {
      border-bottom-color: #222; } }
.nav__toggle {
  display: none; }
  @media (max-width: 799px) {
    .nav__toggle {
      display: block;
      position: absolute;
      right: 1rem;
      top: 1rem; } }
.search {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 1rem; }

.search__toggle {
  appearance: none;
  order: 1;
  font-size: 0;
  width: 34px;
  height: 34px;
  background: url("../img/header-3/search.svg") center right/22px no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  display: none; }
  @media (min-width: 800px) {
    .search__toggle {
      border-left: 1px solid #979797;
      padding-left: 10px; } }
  @media (max-width: 799px) {
    .search__toggle {
      position: absolute;
      right: 5.5rem;
      top: 0.65rem;
      background: url("../img/header-3/search.svg") center/22px no-repeat; } }
.search__form {
  display: block; }
  .search__form.active {
    display: block; }
  @media (max-width: 799px) {
    .search__form {
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      right: 0;
      top: 100%; }
      .search__form input {
        width: 100%; } }
  .search__form input {
    min-width: 200px;
    appearance: none;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 0;
    font-size: 16px;
    padding: 0.5rem; }
    @media (max-width: 799px) {
      .search__form input {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #979797; } }
.inactive-item {
  opacity: 0; }

  /*section categories */
  .categories{
  width:100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color:white;
  border:solid 0.2px #979797;
  border-top: none
  }
  table,tr,td{
    background-color:white;
    border:solid 0.2px #979797;
    border-top: none;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding: 20px auto ;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }


    td{
      text-align: center;
      vertical-align: middle;
      transition: color;
    }
    td:hover{
      color: #87ceeb
    }
    @media (max-width: 799px){
      table,tr,td{
        display: inline-block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 30px;
        border:none;
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 30px;
      }
      .categories{
        width:100%;
        background-color:white;
        border:none;
        border-bottom: none;
        margin-top:300px;
        }
        td{
          border-top:#979797 0.2px solid;
          padding-top: 20px
        }

    }
  .test{
    width: 500px;
    height: 250px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background-color: #222222
  }
```

Comment: You may need to research more about how to layout a site with html and css--specifically look at position: absolute--that may not be the right solution here. There are a lot of resources online including [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Introduction) and [W3 Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/css/default.asp).

Answer (score -1):

I'd recommend you to download your svg files and putting them in a folder (rather than inputting them in the code directly). It's quite difficult to read your code with them adding so much noise.

Also I'm not sure what do you mean its not showing completely. I just see a black rectangle. It is showing correctly? Or is it not the container below? I'd appreciate if you were more specific on what exactly isn't showing.

```
<div class="container-sm test">100% wide until small breakpoint</div>
```

this doesn't have any style changes except whatever bootstrap sends so I'd recommend also checking on bootstrap's documentation.